# Is there any way to generate BIML from SSIS packages?

Tags: ssis, biml

It is common to generate SSIS packages from BIML. But is there any way to generate BIML from SSIS packages? So we can reuse old SSIS packages without writing new BIML.

Comment: Your question is "How can I turn an existing package into Biml" not "Can I generate Biml from an SSIS package" yeah?

Comment: yes, that is correct. I mean the synchronization between BIML en SSIS and vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to do this with [BimlOnline](http://bimlonline.com/) and its free. I have not personally tried it so I cannot speak to how well it works. Also, the service is in Beta so your mileage may vary. I found this out through Cathrine Wilhelmsen who wrote a [blog post](https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2015/11/17/get-started-with-bimlonline-beta/) about this on 11/17/2015.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious (but most expensive) answer is to use BimlStudio (the very sparkly brand new version of Varigence Mist).

For those who are not aware, BimlStudio is the commercial integrated development platform for BIML.  It does have some decent features, with one of the most useful being the ability to import packages and projects.  Once they are in BimlStudio, Biml code is generated, which can be inspected/modified as required.

But, be warned - it doesn't handle everything with grace.  I have had issues with converting script tasks, which required adding additional references within BimlStudio (I was using V4), compared to what was being used within Visual Studio (2015).

Comment: Some additional information would probably be beneficial to improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: Is that enough info now?

Answer (score 1):

You can now also download ["BIML Express" Visual Studio extension](https://varigence.com/bimlexpress).

This extension adds a right-click menu option to generate BIML from an DTSX file. There are also a couple of other source options (e.g. SSIS project file) but I haven't looked at them.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a trial version of BIMLStudio for 14 days.

Launch BIMLStudio -> go to Import tab -> Import Packages -> Select package under "Path" -> Select import.

It will convert the SSIS package as a BIML package.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if your are on SSIS you can simply right click on the package and select
**Convert SSIS Packages to Biml**

You will get the converted file (.biml) in Miscellaneous.